# How to remove specific phrases in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have transcripts of online customer service interactions in Sheets that I would like to anonymize. They are formatted like so:

09:11:37 - Jane Doe : Good morning!

09:12:00 - John Smith : Hello!

The entire sheet has many many different names and hundreds of interactions, so find and replace is still tedious. Is there a way to isolate everything between "-" and ":" and either replace or delete on each line? I found examples of similar things, but could never get the syntax quite right.

Also open to other ideas or tool suggestions!

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression

```
=regexreplace(A1,"(\-.*: )","")
```

Comment: I fiddled with that for so long and it was right in front of me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just a little idea, I would give.

You can use `SEARCH()` to find where `:` and `-` is and you can extract the sub string from the text.

Example:

`A3` has "09:11:37 - Jane Doe : Good morning!"

`LEFT(A3, SEARCH(" - ", A3) - 1)` would give me `09:11:37` and what basically we are doing is getting Substring from the beginning of the text.

`MID(A3, SEARCH(" : ", A3) + 3 , 100000)` would give be `Good morning!`

now finally use `CONCATENATE` to join these strings as

`= CONCATENATE( LEFT(A3, SEARCH(" - ", A3) - 1), " ", MID(A3, SEARCH(" : ", A3) + 3 , 100000))`

Now you will get the string as `09:11:37 Good morning!`

Hope that works. Play around with the formula cheat sheet.

Reference: https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en